# Encountering "cannot shut down device 1" error when loading SoupX in Jupyter Notebook using %%R magic

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, rpy2

I'm trying to load the SoupX library from R using %%R R magic but I'm encountering a dev.off() error:

```
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('R', '', 'library(SoupX)\n#Loads R packages required for ambient RNA correction\n')
-> 2478     result = fn(*args, **kwargs)

--> 981         ro.r('dev.off()')

--> 501     res, visible = rinterface.evalr_expr_with_visible(   # type: ignore
502         r_expr
503     )

RRuntimeError: Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)`
```

It loads normally in R, the problem seems to be related to Jupyter Notebook

I loaded these modules

```
import rpy2.rinterface_lib.callbacks as rcb
import rpy2.robjects as ro

rcb.logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
ro.pandas2ri.activate()
anndata2ri.activate()

%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

and tried running:

```
%%R
library(SoupX)
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with dev.off() in Jupyter Notebook? Are there specific considerations for using graphical devices in Jupyter Notebook with the %%R magic command?